# Null GrantedAuthority to get UserDetails on Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

This is my UserDetails service in spring security:

```
public class UserDetail implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    User_service user_service;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true; 
        com.domain.User user = user_service.findByUserName(userId);
        return new User(user.getUserId(), user.getPassword(), enabled,
                            accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, 
                            accountNonLocked, this.getGrantedAuthorities(user));
    }

    public List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(com.domain.User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> role_name = null;
        List<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
        try {
            for(Role role : roles) {
                role_name.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getName()));
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        return role_name;
    }

}
```

And I am getting this exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Cannot  pass a null GrantedAuthority collection
at   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at      org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.sortAuthorities(User.java:146)
at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.<init>(User.java:108)
```

In `getGrantedAuthorities` method user object is found, I test it, but when I want to add the role name to GrantedAuthority list, it throws an exception "Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection". Why GrantedAuthority returnning null?

I am pretty sure that "user" object is not null, i checked it.

Answer (score 6):

Your **`role_name`** is null. Try change `List<GrantedAuthority>role_name=null;` by `List<GrantedAuthority>role_name=new ArrayList<>();`.

Also, `user.getRoles()` should be returning an empty collection.

Comment: No.user.getRoles() doesn't returning an empty collection.I am sure about that because i print it.

Comment: Well, the error is `Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection`, so `getGrantedAuthorities` returns a null value. Try at least initialize `role_name` and test. Furthermore, `role_name.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getName()));` will throw a NPE, since `role_name` is not initialized, or no?